# ZFS Samba share not creating usershare

Tags: samba, zfs, ubuntu-18.04

I have been trying to get zfs to share itself over the network using Samba by following a few supposedly simple steps. I first installed zfs and Samba then created a pool which all works fine. Next I modified `smb.conf` to add the following properties (and restarted the service after):

```
usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
usershare max shares = 100
usershare allow guests = yes
usershare owner only = no
```

Next I ran `sudo pdbedit -a username` to add a new Samba user. Finally I ran `sudo zfs set sharesmb=on storage` (where `storage` is the name of my pool). Through this whole process there were no errors or anything but upon attempting to connect there are no shares present.

Connecting using `smbclient -L localhost` shows:

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (fruitydelight server (Samba, Ubuntu))
```

Additionally, `sudo net usershare list` shows no results, nor is there a usershare file in `/var/lib/samba/usershares`.

Explicitly running `sudo zfs share storage` indicates the following which suggests that zfs does think it is actually properly sharing it I assume:

`cannot share 'storage': filesystem already shared`

Am I doing something wrong or is this just an issue with Samba's integration into zfs?

For some additional info, I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04, my zfs version is `0.7.5-1ubuntu16.6` and my Samba version is `Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu`. The output from `sudo testparm` can be seen below:

```
[global]
        deadtime = 30
        disable spoolss = Yes
        dns proxy = No
        load printers = No
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        min receivefile size = 16384
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        printcap name = /dev/null
        server min protocol = SMB2
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        show add printer wizard = No
        syslog = 0
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        usershare owner only = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        aio read size = 1
        aio write size = 1
        printing = bsd
        smb encrypt = desired
        use sendfile = Yes
        write cache size = 262144
```

Comment: i dont use the zfs share i use only native configuration on samba to share and this works fine without interacting With zfs tools

Comment: @djdomi Yeah I might as well just do that, was just trying to do it the "right" way or whatever but it's just being uncooperative.

Comment: i understand your thoughts, but use the samba only config it makes it easier